# How can I further compress a JPEG to send over a TCP Stream in C/C++ on Windows?

Tags: c++, tcp, screenshot

I am making my own version of teamviewer, where you can show your screen to other people so that they can help you with issues and provide support.  However, I have ran into a slight issue.

Firstly, when I take a screenshot the .BMP is about 1 MB in memory.  After using EncodingParams and converting it to a JPEG with ulong quality = 20, it drops to 92 kb.  However, I still feel like this might be a little too big to constantly send over a stream.

Is there any way I can reduce the size of an image or any kind of way I can make it less network intensive?  Every single byte I remove would help speed it up for slower connections, and use less bandwidth.

I would appreciate if someone could give me some advice.

Thanks

Comment: This is why screen-sharing applications don't usually send the whole screen, they just send changes.

Comment: In general, trying to compress already-compressed data is futile. This is because compressed data looks a lot like random data, and random data is not compressible.

Comment: Reminds of the myths I heard as a kid, "zip a zip file to get even better compression; even better if you zip it, then rar it, then zip it again, etc ...". It was probably a misconception caused by the icons they used, showing a file cabinet being squished by a clamp through sheer force.

Comment: JPEG would be the wrong format for screen sharing anyway. It's a **photo** format (hence the P in JPEG). It works great on swatches of blue sky. Computer screens tend to have *identical* shades of blue, though. PNG is more appropriate for those scenarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use a lower quality than 20, or or reduce the size of the image. Both will of course degrade the quality. But there aren't any obvious compression techniques that you can use on a JPEG compressed image - it's about as small as it will get (even high quality JPEG's will compress rather poorly, because JPEG does a good job at compressing the actual data in the image, as well as "destroying" pixels when compression levels are quite high). You can prove this by taking a number of JPEG images and compress them with your favourite compression program (ZIP, GZIP, BZIP, etc).

You can also reduce the number of colours in the image - a 256 (8-bit) or 64K (16-bit) image will compress much better than a 16M (24/32-bit) image.

Other obvious answer is to only send the DIFFERENCE between one frame and another - this can give you pretty decent benefits as long as the picture isn't changing very much - if someone is playing a "shoot-em up" type game, where things explode and the scene changes at 50 fps, it's probably not going to help much, but for regular office type applications, the number of pixels that change each frame is probably minimal.

Comment: Reducing the amount of colors is no solution. Doing so creates banding effects. That is a high-frequency effects, which compresses poorly in JPEG. In exchange you lose gradients, which are low-frequency effects that JPEG compresses well. The main solution is in fact the last one. And even games video compresses well, using a  relevant compression algorithm such as H264.